# How to pass JSON data to AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS. I try to create a reusable component called .

Unfortunately I cannot prefill the fields inside  element with the data obtained from JSON.
I looked around SO and the web but could not solve it. Could you please let me know what am I doing wrong?

I have two controllers. One gets a list of all countries:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'Countries',
                                  function ($scope, Countries) {
  $scope.countries = Countries.query();
}]);
```

The other gathers a specific address:

```
app.controller('AddressesController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Address',
  function($scope, $routeParams, Address) {

    if ($routeParams.addressId) {
      $scope.senderAddress = Address.get({addressId: $routeParams.addressId});
    } else {
      $scope.senderAddress = {"id":null, "country":null, "city":null, "street":null};
    }

    $scope.adData = {"id": 1, "country": "Poland", "city": "Warsaw", "street": "Nullowska 15"};
  }]);
```

The services are defined as follows, they seem to work correctly and provide correct JSONs:

```
myServices.factory('Countries', ['$resource',
                                function($resource) {
                                  return $resource('data/countries.json', {}, {
                                    query: {method:'GET'}
                                  })
                                }]);
myServices.factory('Address', ['$resource',
                               function($resource) {
                                 return $resource('data/:addressId.json', {}, {
                                   query: {method:'GET', params:{addressId:'addressId'}}
                                 })
                               }])
```

I have routing set so that it directs to AddressesController:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/address', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/addresses.html',
    controller: 'AddressesController'
  })
  .when('/address/:addressId', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/addresses2.html',
    controller: 'AddressesController'
  })
});
```

The partial view is simple, I create 2  elements

```
<label> Sender </label>
<address address-data='{{senderAddress}}'></address> <!-- I tried all combinations of passing this as argument -->

<label> Receiver </label>
<address></address>
```

Now the directive is declared as:

```
app.directive("address", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "/directives/address.html",
    scope: {addrData: '@senderAddress'},
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      scope.adData = attributes["addressData"];
    }
  }
});
```

and template for it is:

```
<div> 

<label> {{senderAddress}} </label> <!-- senderAddress from Addresses Controller is filled correctly -->
<div>
    <label>Country</label>
    <select>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option ng-repeat="country in countries.countries" value="{{country}}">{{country}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    <label>City {{dto.adData.city}}</label>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="dto.adData.city"  /> <!-- this I cannot pre-fill -->
</div>

<div>
    <label>Street{{data.adData.city}}</label>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="dto.adData.street"> <!-- this I cannot pre-fill -->
</div>

</div>
```

It all works well outside of directive. But I miss something regarding how to handle the scope inside a directive with data being obtained from JSON service. Is it because JSON data is a promise object when the links to the directive are created? How to handle it?

PS

I also tried observing the attributes:

```
link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      //scope.dto.adData = attributes["addressData"];
      attrs.$observe('addressData', function(data) {
        if (!data)
          return;
        scope.dto.adData = data;
      })
    }
```

Even for statically defined data it doesn't work:

```
app.directive("address", function () {
  return {

    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.dto = {};
      $scope.dto.data = {"id": 1, "country": "Poland", "city": "Warsaw", "street": "Nullowska 15"};
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing in the JSON like this isn't how I'd do it as it's kind of hacking in the data binding and you probably don't get two-way binding. I'd use an [isolate scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive).

Your directive would be used without handlebars, to link up the scope variable:

```
<address address-data='senderAddress'></address>
```

And then you'd include a `scope` option in the directive definition:

```
app.directive("address", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "/directives/address.html",
    scope: {
        addressData: '='
    }
  }
});
```

The bare equals-sign `'='` tells Angular to double-bind the parent scope variable referenced in the address-data attribute to the child scope variable addressData. This is done automatically by normalizing the name "address-data" into the JS-style "addressData." If you wanted to name the two scope variables differently, you could do `innerAddressData: '=addressData'` instead.

If you do it like this, you don't need a linking function at all and the binding still should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's an elegant solution. I just wonder about this Angular Best Practices excerpt: "Always let users use expressions whenever possible
ng-href and ng-src are plaintext attributes that support {{}}
Use $attrs.$observe() since expressions are async and could change",  isn't then observing the attributes worthwile?

Comment: I believe that best practice is referring to situations where you're dealing with plaintext values. Here you're using JSON data; unless you want to include handlebars expressions inside your JSON (which is, I think, a mistake) I don't think this best practice is relevant.

Observing the attributes will probably work depending on what you want to do. It's only a one-way binding, though; if you change the data within the directive scope it won't change the data in the parent scope.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved it, in case anyone has similar issues, it may help to check if the scope is set to true and to check if JSON is parsed from string ;-).

```
app.directive("address", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "/directives/address.html",
    scope: true, // creates its own local scope
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {

      attributes.$observe('addressData', function(data) {
        if (!data)
          return;
        scope.dto = {};
        // works almost fine but in 2nd case data is also filled
        scope.dto.adData = angular.fromJson(data);

      })
    }
  }
});
```